# server sometimes returns chunked transfer encoding

Tags: php, api

I'm building a REST API.. Sometimes the server returns the response with chunked transfer encoding? Why is that?!

Why can't the server always return the response in the same encoding?

The problem is that I don't know how to read the data when its returned as chunked!?

## update

neeed moore downvotes... to breeeath...

Comment: Do you have any sample code?  Its kind of hard to tell you whats wrong with out seeing what is going on.

Comment: I can't show any code.. I need to know why the server sometimes return responses with chunked encoding

Comment: anyone..? why does the server return both content-length responses and chunked responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your server is using Apache, this is expected behaviour. You can disable it by putting this line in your `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv downgrade-1.0
```

However, you should consider modifying your reading code to just support different content encodings. What library are you using to make the HTTP request? Any reasonable HTTP library can handle chunked requests. If your requesting code is written in PHP, use curl. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/155558/how-can-i-disable-transfer-encoding-chunked-in-apache-with-http-1-1-responses):

1. specify the "Content-Length' header, so server knows, what's the size of the response
2. use HTTP 1.0 at the requester's side

Answer (score 0):

A problem may be that Apache is gzipping your download, taking care of correcting the Content-Length, or in your case, adding the header

> Content-Encoding: chunked

You can add a `.htaccess` RewriteRule to disable gzip:

```
RewriteRule . - [E=no-gzip:1]
```