# iOS - Is it possible to cache the chunked HTTP response?

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, chunked-encoding, nsurlcache

I'm getting data from backend using AFNetworking and set request's `cachePolicy` as `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy`. 
The response headers contain ETag value and `Transfer-Encoding` is `chunked`. 
[image: Chunked Response]

In the second time I call the same API, it gets the fresh data instead of getting from cache as expected.

I notice that if the response is not chunked (contain `Content-Length` header), caching work perfectly 
[image: not chunked response]

My question is: **is it possible to cache `chunked` response in iOS**? 
Thank you for any advice

Comment: I think you might find my answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248707/nsurlcache-inconsistent-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLCache`, which AFNetworking uses for caching, doesn't support caching this type of request.

You could try:

- using `SDURLCache`, an open-source alternative that gives you more control, or
- subclassing `NSURLCache` yourself to roll your own implementation
- using requests that have supported caching headers

Comment: Do you have any official document saying NSURLCache doesn't support?

Comment: from the NSURLRequest documentation: "If you are making HTTP or HTTPS byte-range requests, always use the NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData policy. To learn more, read Caching Byte-Range Requests."